# Foundation Email: Make

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, html-email

Hey guys I'm just starting out with Foundation and it is fantastic.

I just have trouble coming up with an email design. See picture below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFp5S.jpg)

I wanted to come up with those panels so I thought I'd use callouts. However, the spacing and image are weird in smaller screens. This is the [code I came up with(link to foundation thread)](https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/50532-make-callout-card-responsive)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How does it look on smaller screens? Can you supply a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already fixed. Decided to go with the usual tables for grids instead of doing callouts.